# Validation of repetition of name in sql DB?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jframe

I am trying to check whether the name of user exists in my database - or not. I've used the following logic and although the error appears but it also stores the data of the user in the database.

The general thing is, if error appears, no process should be going on unless the error is solved.

But it still stores the name and other stuff. And yeah, I am trying to apply checks (which I'm not very good at)

```
String checkName="SELECT * FROM administrator WHERE name1='"+name+"'";
Pstat = con.prepareStatement(checkName);
rs = Pstat.executeQuery();

if(rs.next())
{
    nameTextField.setText(null);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter Different Name","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Here `Pstat` is an instance of `PreparedStatement`, `con` is an instance of `Connection`, and `rs` is an instance of `ResultSet`.

`adminstrator` is the table name and `name1` is the column name.

Apologies, I've recently switched from c++ to Java. Don't know much about checks.

I get an error

> Please Enter Different Name

but when I click **Ok**, I get another pop up

> Your data is entered

(this pop up is user made so no worries how java got so intelligent regarding to data entry)

And yeah i know a little about `next()`. But I couldn't understand it in `if` statement....

Can somebody tell me whats happening in back-end of this `if` statement?

Comment: The `if` statement just checks if user exists, clears some text field and pops up an error message - and after that the code flow continues as if user _does not_ exist.  Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: and what about `regex` ? i used regex too but the outcome was same as `if`. it showed pop up of error and still entered the data

Comment: A tip - whenever you are asking a question, please provide the full code you are referring to, as @AlexRudenko pointed out. Best way to do this is make a public Git repo of your code on Github or BitBucket, and add the repo's link to the question description. And then mention which code files you are specifically referring to by giving filenames and sharing snippets. Will make everyone's life a litte bit easier. There's no way people will correctly guess what you're doing above and below the snippet. And definitely not on StackO. Except me. In some cases. Only if it's obvious enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening in the backend of the `if(rs.next())`:

1. When your code execution reaches the `if()`, it executes the
   `rs.next()`.
2. Depending on the result of your query, the ResultSet object `rs`
   either has zero or more results.
3. The `rs` object maintains a pointer to all the records it contains.
   Initially, this pointer points to a sort of "dummy" location before
   the actual record.
4. E.g. if there are three records in the `rs` object, say [0,1,2],
   then initially the pointer points to -1.
5. Every time you call `next()` on `rs`, the pointer is moved one place
   forward and if there is a record present on the new location,
   `next()` returns `true`.
6. If there is no record present on the new location, `next()` returns
   `false`.
7. For the sake of your question, assume that there is a record
   available, and `rs.next()` returns `true`.
8. Hence, the execution enters inside the `if()` body.
9. `rs.next()` is usually called inside a loop if more than one record
   is expected from a select query, but since there's no loop in your
   code, `rs.next()` executes only once. That's it, there isn't
   anything else happening with it. On to the `if()` body then.
10. Here, the compiler executes the code that you have written i.e. setting the
    `nameTextField`'s text to `null` and showing a pop-up with your
    error message.
11. Then, the compiler waits for the error dialog to be closed (I
     think, not sure about this step as it's been too long, but go look at the javadocs to see whether `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` is non-blocking or blocking).
12. But the code execution doesn't stop here, and this is where things seem
     to get fishy in your code.
13. In the code you have provided with this question, you do not have any `return` or `throw` or `break` before your `if()` body ends.
14. So what the compiler does is it simply exits the `if()` body and
     continues executing whatever code comes below - which I am assuming
     is for inserting data, and that's where your "Data has been
     inserted" pop-up is coming from.

Adding a `return` statement or throwing an `Exception` just below `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`, inside the `if(rs.next())` should solve your problem, assuming my assumption regarding the missing code is correct.

`Ciao!`